# Django travel up or down relationships in a generic way

Tags: django, generics, view, relationships, django-generic-views

I am trying to rewrite my Django code to make it as generic as possible on all levels. Say I have the following models:

```
class Tvshow(models.Model):
    pass

class Season(models.Model):
    tvshow = models.ForeignKey(Tvshow)

class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
```

A tvshow has seasons, and a season has episodes. I left all other info out for simplicity.

My detail view for any of these objects can now handle any model by using DetailView. But I would also like to display the relations for an object, either parents or children. Let's say you are viewing a tvshow. I can't call on tvshow.season_set.all() to display this information because my template doesn't know it's dealing with a tvshow (nor that tvshows have seasons). Instead, I would like to be able to do this:
object.children_set.all().

That way I can feed my view any of these 3 models, and it will work. Is this possible?

p.s. I know the object. part works, but will the children part work also? There is one ugly hack I was able to come up with: use the relation_name property to name all relations children. I suppose it would work but it is not a direction I want to take.

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ObjectDetailView(DetailView):  
    template_name = "detail.html"
```

urls.py

```
from tvshows.views import ObjectDetailView
from tvshows.models import Tvshow

urlpatterns = patterns('tvshows.views',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ObjectDetailView.as_view(model = Tvshow), name='detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to do this. However, if your only goal is have one view that works for all three, you could do something like:

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if hasattr(context['object'], 'season_set'):
            context['children'] = context['object'].season_set.all()
        elif hasattr(context['object'], 'episode_set'):
            context['children'] = context['object'].episode_set.all()

        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That would work, to bad it always has to be something like this because that way I would still need to define the rules somewhere. That means it is not truly generic.

I think I will solve it by having a different template for each which will inherit from a generic parent.